# Automatically appending Excel tables to themselves

Tags: python, excel, pandas, append, openpyxl

I am attempting to write some code where for every time I run a python script a data frame (that has been made) automatically becomes a excel table in a defined folder path. However I want it to work in such a way that by re running the code the data frame would append to the end of the existing excel table, creating a new excel table. Currently I am using this code to do the data overlap:

```
def append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name='Sheet2', startrow=None, startcol=None,
    truncate_sheet=False, resizeColumns=True, na_rep = 'NA', **to_excel_kwargs):
    """
    Append a DataFrame [df] to existing Excel file [filename]
    into [sheet_name] Sheet.
    If [filename] doesn't exist, then this function will create it.

    Returns: None

    """
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    from string import ascii_uppercase
    from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
    from openpyxl import Workbook

    # ignore [engine] parameter if it was passed
    if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
        to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

    try:
        f = open(filename)
        # Do something with the file
    except IOError:
        # print("File not accessible")
        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active
        ws.title = sheet_name
        wb.save(filename)

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists = 'overlay')


    # Python 2.x: define [FileNotFoundError] exception if it doesn't exist
    try:
        FileNotFoundError
    except NameError:
        FileNotFoundError = IOError


    try:
        # try to open an existing workbook
        writer.book = load_workbook(filename)

        # get the last row in the existing Excel sheet
        # if it was not specified explicitly
        if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row

        # truncate sheet
        if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            # index of [sheet_name] sheet
            idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
            # remove [sheet_name]
            writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
            # create an empty sheet [sheet_name] using old index
            writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)

        # copy existing sheets
        writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # file does not exist yet, we will create it
        pass

    if startrow is None:
        # startrow = -1
        startrow = 0

    if startcol is None:
        startcol = 0

    # write out the new sheet
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, startcol=startcol, na_rep=na_rep, **to_excel_kwargs,header = False, index = False)

    
    ws = writer.book[sheet_name]

    
    if resizeColumns:

        def auto_format_cell_width(ws):
            for letter in range(1,ws.max_column):
                maximum_value = 0
                for cell in ws[get_column_letter(letter)]:
                    val_to_check = len(str(cell.value))
                    if val_to_check > maximum_value:
                        maximum_value = val_to_check
                ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(letter)].width = maximum_value + 2

        auto_format_cell_width(ws)
    
    writer.save()
```

This code successfully allows me to run the code as many times as i want and append the data onto the end of the previously ran python script. However those outputted excel sheets are not in table format.

Currently my attempt to make a table is as follows:

```
ws = writer.book[sheet_name]

    def make_table(worksheet, df):

      column_settings = []
      for header in df.columns:  
        column_settings.append( header)

      

      table = Table(displayName="Contacts", ref="A1:" + get_column_letter(worksheet.max_column) + str(worksheet.max_row))
      table._initialise_columns()
      for column, value in zip(table.tableColumns, column_settings):
        column.name  = value

      worksheet = worksheet.add_table(table)
```

However the column names do not update accordingly in the excel sheet, excel cites an error for this along the lines of 'had to recover/delete unworkable parts'

But also upon trying to run the script a second time the following python error:
'Table with name Contacts already exists'
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here is a toy data frame for testing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: @Himanshuman what else do i need to provide for a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Table names have to be unique in a workbook. Also, focus the code on creating multiple tables: the dataframe stuff isn't really relevant.

Comment: @CharlieClark So how could i go about solving this problem, as i need it all in one table every time its run but obviously the length of the data will change etc

Comment: at the end of `make_table()` you should use `return worksheet` and later run as `worksheet = make_table(worksheet, df)`